# Ionic/angular 2 nested lists index(numbering)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

**Hi all, I have nested ngFor with indexes(See code below).**

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categoriesWithFoodies; let catIndex = index">
<span>{{catIndex}}</span>
<ul class="foodies-list">
    <li *ngFor="let foodie of category.foodies; let foodIndex = index">
        <span>{{foodIndex}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Now food indexes are like this:**

**cat 1**

food 1
  food 2
  food 3

**cat 2**

food 1
  food 2

**cat 3**

food 1
  food 2

**And i need them to be like this:**

**cat 1**

food 1,
  food 2,
  food 3

**cat 2**

food 4,
  food 5

**cat 3**

food 6,
  food 7

**Do you know how to achive this?**

Answer (score 0):

I reckon this is an ideal place to add an [angular pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

So I am not 100% that this is the best implementation but the idea behind it is to return the real index of `category.foodies` no matter where in the parent loop you are.

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({
    name: 'realIndex',
 })
 export class RealIndexPipe implements PipeTransform {

    private _lastIdx: number = 0; //store the last index

    transform(value: any, idx: number, last: boolean) {

    let returnNum: number = 0;
    if (last) {
       this._lastIdx = this._lastIdx + idx + 1;
       returnNum = this._lastIdx;
    } else {
       returnNum = idx + 1 + this._lastIdx;
    }
    return returnNum;
 }
}
```

So here I am setting a private value (`private _lastIndex`) that will hold the last indexed value in a single loop, independent of the parent loop. So if the last item has an index of `3` then that will hold that value of 3 to be used in the next iteration. Then in the conditional for `last` that index gets updated with the new last index value plus the current value of `_lastIndex`, plus `1` to take into account that the index starts at `0`. And then just returns that value to the view.

But if it is not the last in the child loop then take the `_lastIndex` plus its current index plus `1` ( again just taking into account that the index starts at `0` ).

So then in the view we can add the `last` into the `*ngFor` and add the pipe for the looped values

```
<li *ngFor="let foodie of category.foodies; let foodIndex = index; let lastOfFood = last">
    <span> {{foodie}} {{foodIndex | realIndex: foodIndex: lastOfFood}} </span>
</li>
```

There might be another way to do it based on `category.foodies.length` which might be more ideal depending on the functionally.